# Draw a non linear graph in jQuery + Plotting [Final output attached]

Tags: php, jquery, graph, charts

I want to draw a graph.
I am using http://canvasjs.com/ to draw the chart. But the graph which i am trying to achieve is non-linear.

**So is there anyway that i can plot those points just like the below image?**

Image of Final Output
[image]

Data points are variables and it will change time to time . i am not sure which way i need to go ?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @ Cerlin Boss for edit :)